# How to open a VS 2013 project, when the error is : Access to the path ....csproj is denied

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

I moved from a pc to another. 
Installed VS 2013 and everything that I think I need.

I got the source files from TFS, but when I launch the solution, all the project return an error message "Access to the path ... .csproj is denied"

I run VS2013 in admin mode, I tried to grant full control to Everyone on my source code folder. I tried to get the source control source code to a new local path.

How can I get my solutions to load the projects properly?

Answer (score 0):

Simply browse to the folder where the files are kept, select them all, and right click those files double check if it's **Read-Only** status. If so, drop a click on that checkbox.